# Strong law of large number

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

Let $ \{c_n\} $ be a descending positive real sequence.

Let $ X_1,X_2,\cdots $ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables.

Is the following equivalent?

($1$) For any i.i.d sequence $ X_1,X_2,\cdots $ such that$ \operatorname{E}(X_1^2)<\infty, \operatorname{E}(X_1)=0$ . $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}c_n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\to 0 $ a.s

($2$) $ \sum\limits_{n}c_n^2<\infty $

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_Two-Series_Theorem

Comment: I would be interested in whether (1) is true when $c_n = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n \log(n)}}$

Comment: @NateEldredge after googling, I believe what you linked shows 2 implies 1, but the OP asked whether they are equivalent. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: but c_n = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n \log(n)}} it's  not good choice , pleas see the law of iterated logarithm

Comment: Actually, the law of iterated logarithm shows that (1) does not imply (2), doesn't it?

Comment: mayeb you mean this :A trivial counter -example is when $ X_1$ is just a constant 

Roughly speaking, it should be equivalent to prove that :


$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{m>n} \sqrt{m}c_m = 0 \Leftrightarrow  \sum_n c_n^2 < \infty$

Comment: @rafik Why is that? If $1/c_n = \sqrt{n \log \log n}$, then the left-hand side equals $0$, but the series does not converge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see to use the law of the iterated logarithm that tell us:
$\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{S_n}{\sqrt {n\log\log n}}\right|=\sigma\sqrt 2\text{ with probability 1,}$

where: $S_n:=X_1+\ldots+X_n$ , and $ \sigma^2=\mathbb EX_1^2$ Hence if :

$ \sqrt{n\log\log n}\cdot c_n\to 0$ .one has $ c_nS_n\to 0$ with probability 1.

This is not quite a necessary and sufficient condition, because we  can construct decreasing sequences
 $(c_n) $ that most of the the time are of smaller order than $1/\sqrt{n\log\log n}$, but occasionally are as big as $1/\sqrt{n\log\log n}$ for which $ c_nS_n\to 0  $still goes to 0 almost surely , but if we want$ c_n$
to be some kind of regularly decaying sequence, then this is exactly the right condition.

i looked this book :The  Theorem 2.5.7, p. 71 :http://www.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/pte.html

Answer (score 1):

Recall the law of the iterated logarithm:

> Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of iid random variables such that $\mathbb{E}(X_1^2)=:\sigma^2<\infty$ and $\mathbb{E}X_n=0$. Then, $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{X_1+\ldots+X_n}{\sqrt{2n \log \log n}} \right| = \sigma \quad \text{a.s.}$$

This means in particular that $(1)$ does not imply $(2)$. In fact, if we choose

$$c_n := \frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n \log \log n}},$$

then it follows from the law of iterated logarithm that

$$c_n \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n X_i = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{\sqrt{n \log \log n}} \to 0.$$

On the other hand,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n \cdot \log n \cdot \log \log n} = \infty.$$

Using a very similar argumentation, one can show that $(2)$ implies $(1)$.